What's the impact on a recipient user account if a "unfriendly or unkind" flag is accepted?
I read:

The flag ["unfriendly or unkind"] if accepted has quite a lot of impact on the account which has been flagged.

What's the impact on a recipient user account if a "unfriendly or unkind" flag is accepted? (recipient user account = user account who wrote the comment that got flagged)

For context: this question was asked in response to this Travel Meta post.

Two options that moderators have will mark a comment flag helpful: delete and edit. If enough unfriendly/unkind comment flags are marked helpful on a user's comments in a short enough timeframe, moderators will see the flag "possible comment abuse: too many abusive or unkind (auto)", which is raised by Community bot automatically. Moderators can do whatever with this flag: ignore, warn, or suspend.
Additionally, moderators can view all of a user's flagged comments by flag type, so not flagging properly makes it inconvenient for moderators to see how much of a problem someone is being in the comments.
This should not be confused with the spam/abusive post flags, which cause the post to be locked/deleted and subtract 100 reputation from the account. (You need 4 of those flags or one from a moderator for this to take effect, however.)

This would make the moderator refusing to accept the flag over this really strange…

"delete and edit" - by whom? The comment author? Or a moderator?

@ShadowWizard They're options when a moderator handles a flag.

"Subtract 100 reputation from the account" Except if the post was on a meta site, then no reputation will be subtracted.

@Starship The moderator probably didn't realize "unfriendly/unkind" comment flags are handled differently from "rude/abusive" post flags. I used to think they were similar too, but it turns out comment flags don't deduct 100 rep. This post cleared it up for me.
